# CSS framework recommendations for long page websites and animation handling?

Tags: web-development, framework, css

I'm looking for a CSS framework to use for a long page website with heavy animations.

Check [this site](http://fuelyourfuture.com.au/) for an example.

My criteria for a good CSS framework is as follows (but by no means a requirement):

- Has features for creating long page websites
- Animation support
- General ease of use (I don't want to type `-moz`, `-webkit`, `-ms` multiple times)
- Employability (it's a bonus if you know that companies are using this framework as well)

Aside from CSS frameworks, you can suggest templating language if you believe it helps.

Comment: That example does not strike me as a *long website*, it's approx. 3 browser heights.

Answer (score 1):

The page you give as an example uses (feel free to add what I missed)

- normalize.css v3.0.1 | MIT License | git.io/normalize
- https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll (JS library, it is not all CSS)
- jQuery

The choice of a CSS framework is almost an impossible one to make objectively. The best I can go is give you a big list and add that I like Bootstrap.

- https://usablica.github.io/front-end-frameworks/compare.html

Templating language definitely helps. Especially to shield you from using vendor specific prefixes. As far as I know, developers of CSS frameworks usually use templating languages themselves. Twitter Bootstrap originally used Less, now there is also a Sass version. Both Sass and Less are a good choice. Pick the one that is supported by your CSS framework. I prefer Sass.

This article shows how Sass helps writing CSS

- http://hugogiraudel.com/2014/07/16/automating-css-animations-with-sass/

My CSS animations library of choice is

- http://geoffgraham.me/animate-scss/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried responsive or bootstrap via http://www.initializr.com? It is very fast to load and many companies do use it because it is cross-browser compatible. (They list companies on the site)